# How can I get text from href?

Tags: javascript, dom

I've got problem with getting this text from href. I'm working on dom and I'd like to get text from this href:

```
<div class='xx'>
  <a href='zz' class='button>
...
```

I was trying to do sth like that:

```
document.getElementById(".xx").getAttribute("href")
```

But it's not working properly

Comment: the href is another element, not an attribute. And ".xx" is a class selector, not an id selector. And what text? There's no text shown in your example. I suggest you take a beginner tutorial, because this looks like guesswork.

Comment: `xx` is a class not an ID. Read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21436550/javascript-how-to-get-only-one-element-by-class-name/21436552

Comment: You are totally right! Comment deleted...

Answer (score 3):

> But it's not working properly

Because

- you don't have an element with `id` attribute `.xx`,
- `.xx` targets the `div` not the *anchor*

Also, your *anchor tag*'s attribute *class* is not closed properly, also closing tag is not given either.

```
<div class='xx'>
  <a href='zz' class='button'>Some text</a>
</div>
```

you have a class so use the class selector itself using `querySelector`

```
document.querySelector( ".xx .button" ).getAttribute( "href" )
```

or simply

```
document.querySelector( ".xx .button" ).href;
```

Comment: zz is not a class

Comment: @CiroSpaciari Thanks, corrected the same using the `button` class now

Comment: While you're at it, you could also point out the error in the html (unclosed attribute value for the `a`'s class)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I am pretty sure that is a typo, will point the same anyways.

Answer (score 2):

`getElementById` will grab an element by that ID. You have an anchor (malformed albeit) with not an ID but a class. Secondly you are targeting the parent div. You should be targeting the  tag using `querySelector()` instead. Then to get the href you'd use `href`.

```js
const href = document.querySelector('.xx .button').href;

console.log(href);
```

```html
<div class='xx'>
  <a href='zz' class='button'></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below will get text from link:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('xx')[0].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].getAttribute("href");
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
document.getElementsByClassName("xx")[0].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].getAttribute("href")
```

Comment: Funny thing is, this overcomplicated answer is the only one that got it right on the first try.

Answer (score 0):

you can use id instead of class because class returns undefined value.and also you tried to get  class using getby id

wrong:

> document.getElementById(".xx").getAttribute("href")

```js
function h()
{
alert(document.getElementById("button").href);
}
```

```html
<a href='zz' id='button' onclick='h();'>
asd</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var yourhref = document.querySelector("div.xx a.button").href
```

`yourhref` holds your requested value. This is as precise as it gets using only the part of code you provided. **If somewhere else on the page** you have a div with class xx and a link with class button you are not gonna have a good time.

**Solution** -  either have your targeted element or parent have UNIQUE id and then write a selection from there.