# Switching between two background colors of a web page with CSS Switch

Tags: javascript

my code works fine I just need to switch between two colors white and black I need help to modify the JavaScript code to turn switch between white and black colors.
-CSS

```css
  <style> 
        h1 { 
            color: green; 
        } 
                
        /* toggle in label designing */ 
        .toggle {
            float: none;
            position : fixed ; 
            display : inline-block; 
            width: 80px;
            height: 38px;
            background-color: grey; 
            border-radius: 30px; 
            border: 2px solid white;
            top: 6px;
            left: 896px;
            
        }   
                
        /* After slide changes */ 
        .toggle:after { 
            content: &#39;&#39;; 
            position: absolute; 
            width: 38px;
            height: 35px; 
            border-radius: 50%; 
            background-color: white; 
            top: -1px; 
            left: 0px;
            
            transition: all 0.5s; 
        } 
                
        /* Toggle text */ 
        p { 
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
            font-weight: bold; 
        } 
                
        /* Checkbox cheked effect */ 
        .checkbox:checked + .toggle::after { 
            left : 38px; 
        } 
                
        /* Checkbox cheked toggle label bg color */ 
        .checkbox:checked + .toggle { 
            background-color: #5ad94d; 
        } 
                
        /* Checkbox vanished */ 
        .checkbox { 
            display : none; 
        } 
    </style>
```

-HTML

```
       <input class='checkbox' id='switch' type='checkbox'/> 
        <label class='toggle' for='switch'> 
            <p>ON   OFF</p> 
        </label>
```

-Javascript

```
<script>

document.getElementById(&quot;switch&quot;).addEventListener(&#39;click&#39;, function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName(&quot;mainWrapper fullWidth&quot;)[0].style.backgroundColor = document.getElementById(&quot;switch&quot;).toggle ? &quot;white&quot; : &quot;black&quot;;
});
    </script>
```

again
my code works fine I just need to switch between two colors white and black I need help to modify the JavaScript code to turn switch between white and black colors.
any ideas ??? thank!

Comment: Where is your `mainWrapper`?

Comment: Note that there is no HTML element with the class "mainWrapper" in the HTML you've provided...

Comment: @PraneetDixit it's my website main page it's a lots of code the important part is the background color to be changed

Comment: @HereticMonkey it's my website main page it's a lots of code the important part is the background color to be changed

Comment: Have a read of [mcve] - the emphasis on *complete*.

Comment: @user14775523 so you need to change the background color for each of the element with `mainWrapper` class?

Comment: In any case, the problem is you're using `getElementsByClassName` like it returns a single element. It doesn't, as the link in my first comment explains.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a collection/array so you need to iterate them - or just use jquery (as you've tagged [jquery]) - `$("#tog-bg").click(function() { $(".mainWrapper").css("background-color", this.checked ? "white" : "black")})`

Comment: @freedomn-m  my mainWrapper is `.mainWrapper{margin:0 auto;background-color:#fff;box-shadow:0 0 10px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1)}`

Comment: Can you provide your mainWrapper code ?

Comment: @HereticMonkey  my mainWrapper is `.mainWrapper{margin:0 auto;background-color:#fff;box-shadow:0 0 10px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1)}` when I change the background color it works great I just need to make the button do it , do you feel me?

Comment: Alternative possible answer: [How to get only one element by class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21436550/javascript-how-to-get-only-one-element-by-class-name/21436552)  In summary: use `document.getElementsByClassName("mainWrapper")[0].style...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName()` returns an `html collection object`. It is a collection. If you want to find the first element with the class, you need to use the index `[0]` like below -

```
document.getElementById("tog-bg").addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName("mainWrapper")[0].style.backgroundColor = document.getElementById("tog-bg").checked ? "white" : "black";
});
```

If you want to do this for all elements with the specified class, then you can loop it like below -

```
document.getElementById("tog-bg").addEventListener('click', function(){
    for(let i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("mainWrapper").length; i++){
        document.getElementsByClassName("mainWrapper")[i].style.backgroundColor = document.getElementById("tog-bg").checked ? "white" : "black";
    }
});
```

I am using the ternary operator instead of if else condition in the above snippet. Also, I have replaced the `change` event with `click` event in the listener.

Comment: your code worked!! but I need to switch between colors when button clicked@Praneet Dixit

Comment: @user14775523 What do you mean by "Switch between Colors"? Do you want to change the text color?

Comment: NO background colors, white and black

Answer (score 0):

`getElementByClassName` returns collection

So code should be

```js
//add [0] to both getElementByClassName
document.getElementsByClassName("mainWrapper")[0].style.backgroundColor
```

Also there isn't any class mainWrapper here so you should create a parent div with class `mainWrapper`

Comment: I know this ,  but your code is not for a button that will SWITCH between white and black color for the mainWrapper when the user press it

Comment: @user14775523 you should be able to adapt what has been provided here (which matches my comment *and* the linked question) into your code... it's just a matter of adding `[0]` in two places in your code to get it to work...

Comment: @freedomn-m i'm dumb sorry I don't know how to do it

Comment: @user14775523 fair enough - your code has this twice `document.getElementsByClassName("mainWrapper ").style.backgroundColor = ` you change both of those to this `document.getElementsByClassName("mainWrapper ")[0].style.backgroundColor = ` and you're done  (you might like to copy this comment into a text editor then line up the code to see the difference - the wrapping in this comment may hide the difference)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in firefox (not styled, but functional) :

```
document.getElementById("tog-bg").onclick = function(){
      var e;
    if( (e = document.getElementById("tog-bg")).hasAttribute('checked')) {
      var w = document.getElementsByClassName("mainWrapper ");
      for(i=0;i<w.length;++i)
      {
        w[i].style.backgroundColor = "black";
      }
      e.removeAttribute('checked');
    } else {
      var w = document.getElementsByClassName("mainWrapper ");
      for(i=0;i<w.length;++i)
      {
        w[i].style.backgroundColor = "white";
      }
      e.setAttribute('checked','');
    }
  };
```