# Getting the value of a textarea without an ID - Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the value of a html  that does not have an id.

Code -

```
<section class="post">
  <textarea rows="5" placeholder="(New Post)"></textarea>
</section>
```

JS i've tried::

```
var entryText = document.textarea.value;
var entryText = document.getElementsByTagName.value;
```

Comment: `HTMLElement.getElementsByTagName` will return an HTML collection. You only want to get the value for a single element.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript: How to get only one element by class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21436550/javascript-how-to-get-only-one-element-by-class-name)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the more modern [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) for this task to select the first `textarea` that resides in a `section` block that has the class `post`:

```js
var entryText = document.querySelector("section.post textarea").value;
console.log(entryText);
```

```html
<section class="post">
  <textarea rows="5" placeholder="(New Post)">This is some default text, to show that the call to console.log() works.</textarea>
</section>
```

You may wish to dive further into the documentation for [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors), which is what `document.querySelector()`'s argument takes.