# Why the Value attribute is not added to the HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html like the below,

```
<div id ="b1">
     <div class = "test1"  value = 100> </div>
</div>
```

I need the Value `100` to be displayed in the HTML inside the particular div.

I used the below JS code,

```
Var target = document.getElementById('b1');
var test = target.getElementsByClassName('test');
$(test).innerHTML = $(this).attr('value');
```

*It didnt work.*

Could someone please help?
Many thanks.

Comment: Take a good look at what you're selecting in JS and what you entered in the class attribute. I suggest you open up the browser console (usually by pressing F12 in your browser) when your code isn't working. It displays errors in your code that can give you a hint to what's wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get element by class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965956/how-to-get-element-by-class-name)

Comment: Why are you using both vanilla JS _and_ jQuery in this way? It makes no sense. jQuery objects don't have `innerHTML` properties. Also `getElementsByClassName` returns a live nodelist, so you need to iterate over that. And what is `this` in this example?

Comment: `$(".test1").html(() => $(this).attr("value"));` ?

Comment: @miken32 This won't work, since the keyword `this` refers to the parent object in arrow functions, you'll need to use a regular syntax anonymous function (`function(){}`) to be able to use `this` keyword.

Comment: @AbdElbeltaji good to know; I didn't test it out, just seemed like an obvious one-liner. I'll revise to `$(".test1").html(function() {$(this).attr("value")});`

Answer (score 3):

The [`value` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-value) isn't available on a `<div>`

---

Use `.innerHTML` to change the value of the div
<sup>[HTML/Javascript change div content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554149/html-javascript-change-div-content)</sup>

---

Also, you can use `getElementsByClassName` on the `document` itself, no need to get the parent `<div>` first

---

Since you're only expecting 1 result, well need to select the first index of the nodelist returned by `getElementsByClassName`
<sup>[Javascript: How to get only one element by class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21436550/javascript-how-to-get-only-one-element-by-class-name)</sup>

---

```js
var test = document.getElementsByClassName('test1')[0];
test.innerHTML = 100;
```

```html
<div id="b1">
     <div class="test1"></div>
</div>
```

---

Comment: @OstoneO and Spectric, instead of value can we add <div class = "test" keyVal = 100></div>. is it possible to get the value?

Comment: You'll need to ask an other question about that, not sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Dar No, don't such custom attributes, if you want to use custom attributes you must start its name with `data-` see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes, I also showed it in my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68940898/16618307.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var test= document.getElementById('b2');

test.innerHTML=test.getAttribute("value")
```

```html
   <div id ="b1">
         <div class = "test1" id ="b2"  value="100" > </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score -1):

You have entered the wrong `className`, and you cannot use `this` because it refers to the parent object in this case (`window` object)
you also cannot add a `data` attribute to a div, you can use a special dataset attribute `data-value`:

```
<div id="b1">
  <div class="test1" data-value="100"> </div>
</div>
```

```js
var target = document.getElementById('b1');
var test = target.getElementsByClassName('test1')[0];
test.innerHTML = test.dataset.value;
```

Comment: I used the same as you mentioned, <div class="test1" data-value="100"> </div>, to access the value I used,  var test = target.getElementsByClassName('test1')[0];
test.innerHTML = test.dataset.value; But, It shows dataset undefined.

Comment: @Dar I'm not sure what is wrong! here is a jsFiddle Example: https://jsfiddle.net/4ty8u1pz/